# Flip Animation over array of UIViews in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiview

I am currently trying to achieve Flip Animation iusing Swift. I have a series of defined UIViews which I call in a UIScrollView. 
The idea is that the UIVIews should be easily scrollable and each View can be flipped to see other side of the view; so I have added front side view and back side view.

I have achieved most of it but have an issue: 
When I do flip animation and remove the front view it causes the last UIView to be removed from the list of UIViews. Currently I use viewWithTag to find the View when the user hits the button.

Another issue is when I click on the backView button; I get the wrong tag number; I always get the last View tag number.

```
    for var i = 0; i < 4; ++i {

        frontView.btn.tag = i;
        frontView.btn.addTarget(self, action: "flipView:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside);

        backView.btn.tag = i;
        backView.btn.addTarget(self, action: "flipView:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside);
}
```

I have added code which i have written to achieve this.
Method flipView is called from UIButton Clicks on frontView and backView both to animate back and forth.

```
 func flipView(sender: UIButton){
        self.mainView = self.scrollView.viewWithTag(sender.tag);

        UIView.transitionWithView(self.mainView, duration: 0.5, options:  UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft, animations: {

            if self.flipped == false {
                self.mainView.layoutIfNeeded();
                self.frontView.hidden = true;

                self.frontView.removeFromSuperview();
                self.mainView.addSubview(self.backView);
                self.mainView.layoutIfNeeded();
                self.flipped = true;

            } else {
                self.mainView.layoutIfNeeded();
                self.backView.removeFromSuperview();
                self.frontView.hidden = false;
                self.mainView.addSubview(self.frontView);
                self.flipped = false;
            }

        }, completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: I think your logic around your loop that assigns the tags is wrong.
Can you share how 'frontView' and 'backView' are created and assigned?